# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar este error " AttributeError: module 'plotly.tools' has no attribute 'set_credentials_file'?

Tags: python, jupyter, python-import, plotly

Me estoy iniciando con `plotliy` y en el primer paso ya me he bloqueado al producirse el error que menciono en el título. Trabajo en un entorno virtual con **jupyter notebook**, **python 3.8** y **plotly 4.12**.

La sentencia que produce el error es:

```
import plotly
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='xxxxxx', 
api_key='xxxxxxx')

AttributeError: module 'plotly.tools' has no attribute 'set_credentials_file'
```

Agradeceré sugerencias para resolver este problema.

Comment: se trata de la versión: https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-tools-set-credentials-file/28625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto el problema sustituyendo:

```
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='xxxxxx', 
api_key='xxxxxxx')
```

por:

```
import chart_studio
chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username='xxxxx', api_key='xxxxxxx')
```